# Proper way to set author pages at root?

Tags: wp-redirect, author-template

I want to create landing pages for each user on my site in the same URL structure as most popular social networks:

sitename.com/username

But of course, I don't want to create pages for each user.

My hack way to do it would be to use the 404 page and check if username exists and display a template, but I am assuming there is a proper way to do it with redirects that isn't so hacky.